# [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName() with folder paths

Tags: powershell

I can use `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName()` in place of `Split-Path -leaf` and it works for both directories and files, but for directories it's a little "off label", and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-5.0) don't mention use with directories at all. Is there potential for problems using it this way, like it's basically leveraging a bug that may some day get fixed? or is it just an undocumented "feature"?

Comment: No there is no problem with this and no bug or undocumented feature, its just splitting up a string and returning the last part. There is nothing more to it....  However i don't see why you would want to use this function instead of 'split-path'. When writing powershell scripts it would be best to use powershell functions whereever possible

Comment: While it my work at this moment, the developers do not and do not have to guarantee that it will work in the future. If they change the implementation, you might encounter undefined behaviour. That's why I strongly recommend to not use it.

Comment: @D-J, I tend to use .NET options when available because they are often SO much faster. I just use PowerShell as the glue and logic to connect .NEt stuff. So even when not required, I prefer .NET for consistency and readability. But @stackprotector says this is a place where consistency is also risky, which is what I was concerned about. I COULD use `([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'PATH').Name` but then I need a conditional, since that ALSO works with files and creates the same issue.

Comment: @Gordon directoryinfo.name just calls [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName() internally (see source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,e3b20cb1c28ea93f ))

Comment: @d-j So, further question here. The fact that under the hood this is using `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName()` suggests maybe it's safe, since it's at least still File System. However, I just discovered that `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName()` actually works with registry paths and effectively provides the same result as `Split-Path -leaf`. It's super convenient, but horrible for code readability, and leaves me worried about Microsoft "fixing" this later. REALLY wish they would have a little more rigor and consistency. Ugh.